# What kind of message queues does Spring Cloud Config create?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

*Spring Cloud Config* uses *Spring Cloud Bus* uses *Spring Cloud Stream* to push configuration change events to clients.

My question - since I was yet to find it - is: what kind of queues does Spring Cloud Config create when it starts up? I noticed that it creates topics/queues automatically, but are they **temporary**, i.e. bound to the lifecycle of the server/client or **durable**. Do they have to be removed manually?

**EDIT:** I am using Spring Cloud `Hoxton.SR3` with Spring Boot `2.2.5.RELEASE` (or higher)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which spring cloud stream implementation are you using as it will likely be dependent on that?

Comment: Sorry, stupid me forgot to mention that. It's Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR3 with Spring Boot 2.2.5.RELEASE (or higher)

Comment: are you using amqp or kafka?

Comment: I am running 3 setups right now: 

1. using AMQP / RabbitMQ
2. using Kafka
3. using Solace PubSub+ with their proprietary SMF protocol and Spring Cloud Stream Binder implementation.

From your question, I assume the answer is dependent on the binder implementation. Is that correct?
I guess that would mean that in the Solace PubSub+ case I'd need to get in touch with their developers, right?

Comment: yes, you are correct.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please still shed some light on what the Spring Cloud Stream binders for Kafka and AMQP use as queue types? Thanks.